# Phone-Number RegEx

Tags: regex, phone-number

I need a regex that converts `+442070320811` to `2070 320811`.

Using this regex `\(\d{4})(\d{6})(\d*)$` gives me `4420 703208`

Can anyone advise how I can start the match after the 44?

Comment: possible duplicate of [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search: `\+44(\d{4})(\d{6}\b)`

Replace: `$1 $2` or `\1 \2` depending on language / environment.

Comment: Thanks, I should have mentioned this is javascript.

Comment: Glad it worked, hope to see you again. Hey btw, I notice you haven't yet voted on Stack. If this answer helps and for any answer you find helpful, please consider voting up as this is how the rep system works.:) No obligation of course! Thanks for listening to my 10-second SO rep tut.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
\+\d{2}(\d{4})(\d{6})(\d*)$
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript:

```
text.replace(/(\+44)(\d{4})/g,'$2 ');
```

Java:

```
text.replaceAll("(\\+44)(\\d{4})","$2 ")
```

Simply use regex grouping feature that groups pattern inside parenthesis ().

Online demo on [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/jG2nM5) and [debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/gx2lQgwRjwpGH2tr)

Comment: This worked perfectly for uk numbers but it turns out there are other country codes too so gradi3nt's solution addressed both fortunately.

Comment: You have not mentioned it in your post. If you did it then I will definitely provide you solution as per your need.

Comment: where have you mentioned that what language are you using. Is your question is complete in the context of you original issue?

Comment: You are agree with gradi3nt's solution but still you have accepted other one. Why?

Answer (score 0):

This also worked:

```
^.{2}((\d{4})(\d{6})(\d*)$)
```

Then I could refer to the sections using $2,$3 and $4

Comment: OK so finally you got the answer.

Comment: Have you tested it on the links that I provided you? Is it working?

Comment: Yes, I did test it on those links and it is working fine so thanks for that.